# People who "liked" my Blogger post?

Tags: facebook-like, blogger, facebook-likebox

I have added the following to my Blogger template to add a Like button on each of my Blogger post:

```
<script>
document.write(&#39;&lt;iframe src=&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<data:post.url/>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=380&amp;action=like&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;colorscheme=light&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowTransparency=&quot;true&quot; style=&quot;border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:25px&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&#39;);
</script>
```

My question is, how could I know who exactly has pressed Like as it only display the number of people who have liked my post?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't provide an API to get a list of people who like a page.  This is probably due to privacy issues (although with Facebook you never know their reasonings, they sell your personal information all the time).

Comment: Thanks OffBySome. So I will never gonna know who except my friends have liked my page? No notifications at all? What if somebody liked my old post, I will never know until I review my old posts?

Comment: Google edge.create which you can call in JavaScript to log that someone liked your page, you just won't know who.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how could I know who exactly has pressed Like as it
>   only display the number of people who have liked my post?

Force users to log into your website and only then display the like button for them.  When you hear the `edge.create` event fire then log the user who is logged in.